# Best way to get split from dataframe column values

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with an string column that I wanna to use his values splited on my program.

I had two ways to do this, but I need to know which one are theoretically faster and why:

```py
s1 = [x.split() for x in df[_COLUMN_]]
```

```py
s2= df[_COLUMN_].apply(lambda x: x.split())
```

I runned in a notebook with `%%time` but in my testes I can't see any difference.

I know that result object will be diferent for each way, but I can use both as well.

Comment: `df[your_col].str.split('',expand=True)` would probably be the fastest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the built in `.str` accessor to perform any string operations.

This isn't motivated by performance -- most of the `.str` methods themselves are slower loops over the rows. Instead, the benefit is that these methods have a lot of error handling to deal with cases that crop up because `object` columns might also contain non-string values. In those cases your simple list comprehension or `Series.apply` will fail, but the `.str` accessor handles it and returns a null.

For very very small Series, the list comprehension is by far the best due to the lack of overhead. So if you are certain your inputs are sanitized enough then you can use that.

Below are performance tests to illustrate the timings of three methods against the length of the Series. (I've surpressed the equality check since the list comprehension returns a list, not a Series.

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def list_comp(s):
    return [x.split() for x in s]
    # If you want an equality check
    #return pd.Series([x.split() for x in s], index=s.index)

def series_apply(s):
    return s.apply(lambda x: x.split())

def str_accessor(s):
    return s.str.split()

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda N: pd.Series(np.random.choice(['ab', 'a b, c', 'foo bar', 
                                                'f oo', 'tu ple'], N)), 
    kernels=[
        lambda s: list_comp(s),
        lambda s: series_apply(s),
        lambda s: str_accessor(s)
    ],
    labels=['list_comp', 'series_apply', 'str_accessor'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(23)],
    equality_check=None,
    xlabel='Length of Series'
)
```

[image]

---

To illustrate the error handling built in:

```
s = pd.Series([0, 'foo bar'])

series_apply(s)
#AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

list_comp(s)
#AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

str_accessor(s)
#0           NaN
#1    [foo, bar]
#dtype: object
```